# android transition

Tags: android, android-animation, android-image

I am using the following code to set an animation between 2 images for my SplashScreen:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.splash);

     // Show A Transitions for Splash image here.
    TransitionDrawable transition = (TransitionDrawable) getResources()
            .getDrawable(R.drawable.splash_animation);

    //Set interval for the transition between two image.
    transition.startTransition(5000);

    //Fetch imageView from your layout and apply transition on the same.

    ImageView imageView= (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.splash_image);
    imageView.setImageDrawable(transition);
}
```

My splash.xml is :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ImageView
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:id="@+id/splash_image"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:src="@drawable/img_1" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

My splash_animation.xml file is :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<transition xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
  <item android:drawable="@drawable/img_1"></item>
  <item android:drawable="@drawable/img_2"></item>
</transition>
```

The transition is working fine but I wanted to know if it is possible to create it for 3 images as well. I tried adding a third image in splash_animation but the transition is only done for the first image. How can I achieve it for as many images as I want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put the array of the  `TransitionDrawable`.

```
List<TransitionDrawable>array = new ArrayList<TransitionDrawable>();

TransitionDrawable transition1 = (TransitionDrawable) getResources()
            .getDrawable(R.drawable.splash_animation1); // first,second image

TransitionDrawable transition2 = (TransitionDrawable) getResources()
            .getDrawable(R.drawable.splash_animation2); // third,fourth image

array.add(transition1);
array.add(transition2);
// call array
for(TransitionDrawable transition :array){
transition.start(5000);
}
 ImageView imageView= (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.splash_image);
 imageView.setImageDrawable(transition[0]); // if transition[0] is finished  setImageDrawable(transition[1]);
```

Comment: foreach(Transaction transaction : array)transition.startTransition(5000);

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with any number of images.

You'll need to re-create the TransitionDrawable with the current and next item in the array and update it.

See my answer at https://stackoverflow.com/a/54584103/114549